# Graphically show correlation between columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have the following pandas dataframe covering more than 10k answers for 150 questions.

[image: Pandas Dataframe]

I am struggling to find a way to see the correlation between fields.

In particular I would like to understand how I can graphically show the correlation between Q015 and Q008, knowing that each respondent might have selected multiple answers (1,2,3).

So I am trying to figure out how to graphically display whether there is any correlation between Q015 and Q008 for each selected option of the survey.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can see a linear regression by Pearson

necessary libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
```

Code

```
list_variables, list_COEF, list_MSE, list_RMSE, list_R2SCORE = ([] for i in range(5))
    
# initializing Linear Regression by Pearson
lr = LinearRegression()
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(df[["Q015"]], df[["Q008"]], test_size=0.3)
lr = LinearRegression()
lr_baseline = lr.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
pred_baseline = lr_baseline.predict(xtest)

list_variables.append("Q015 & Q008")
list_COEF.append(round(lr_baseline.coef_[0,0], 4))
list_MSE.append(round(mean_squared_error(ytest, pred_baseline), 2))
list_RMSE.append(round(math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(ytest, pred_baseline)), 2))
list_R2SCORE.append(round(r2_score(ytest, pred_baseline), 2))

# Plotting the graph
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = plt.gca()

plt.suptitle("Q015 & Q008", fontsize=24, y=0.96)
plt.plot(xtest, ytest, 'bo', markersize = 5)
plt.plot(xtest, pred_baseline, color="red", linewidth = 2)
plt.xlabel("Q015", size=14)
plt.ylabel("Q008", size=14)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

You will get something as follows where the column `Coef.` says to you how much the variables are correlated
[image]

Another way is to see the matrix correlation

```
df_corr = pd.DataFrame(df[["Q015", "Q008"]].corr()).round(2)
mask = np.zeros_like(df_corr, dtype=bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True 

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.title("Pearson correlation between features", size=20)

ax = sns.heatmap(df_corr, mask=mask, vmin=-1, cmap="mako_r")

plt.xticks(rotation=25, size=14, horizontalalignment="right")
plt.yticks(rotation=0, size=14)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

An example for numeric columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,15, size=(100, 6)), columns=[["Q01", "Q02", "Q03", "Q07", "Q015", "Q008"]])
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Samir! I tried the first method, but I am stacked on the following point: 
for a, b in itertools.combinations(VARIABLES, 2): NameError: name 'VARIABLES' is not defined

maybe I should declare VARIABLES as the options of column 15? (1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: Sorry, I copy and paste and example based on my code where I use the code with a dict of features. 
I delete the loop. `for a, b in itertools.combinations(VARIABLES, 2):` Try again and let me know.

Comment: Wait a minute, I recently noticed that one of the column allows multiple choices so, it is not the right approach for this situation. Sorry!!

Comment: no problem Samir!!! Actually Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Indeed if I run the code for --->  xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(df[["Q015"]], df[["Q008"]], test_size=0.3)

I get the error: KeyError: "None of [Index(['Q015'], dtype='object', name=0)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Yes, that is because `Q008` is not a numeric column. Maybe you have to consider treating it as a categorical column. Try the first plot with two numeric columns and the second with multiples numeric columns

Comment: I tried with numeric columns like Q001 and Q004, but I see TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235254/discussion-between-samir-hinojosa-and-stefano).